# jQuery Change Color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, this

I am a jQuery beginner and want to achieve the following - whenever I click on any element of the page, I want the color of the text inside it to be changed to red. This is what I have but it doesn't work. Surprisingly the alert statement also prints nothing. But it does executes as I tested it with another alert statement. Thanks.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Cow</div>
    <div>Cat</div>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>coconut</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(this).click(function () {
            var v = $(this).text();
            alert(v); // this prints nothing !!!!
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: And what do you expect `$(this)` to be?

Comment: any element of the page - p, div, a etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you attach the click handler to the `document`, any click that bubbles up to the document will go to the event listener. If you now within the listener look for the `event.target`, that will be the node that initiated the event:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
  $(event.target).css("color", "red");
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/E9H22/

Comment: Thanks Niklas, your approach works correctly but this turned out to be little advanced. I thought my way might just work but it will only work if I used individual selectors.

Comment: @VVV What is you are trying to do, or why wouldn't this approach work for you?

Comment: No your approach works. But I thought my approach should also work and I might have been making some simple mistake. But it turns out we need to use something new (at least for me) to achieve that behavior.

Comment: @VVV Sorry I misunderstood you. The reason your example didn't work was because `this` within the jQuery listener refers to the node you bound the listener to, which in your case is always the `window` object, and as such what your eventually doing is calling `$(window).css('color','red')`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap that in a document ready statement, and attach the click listener to an actual element:

```
$(function(){
  $("*").click(function () {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

Your selector could look something like `$("div, p").click(...)` depending on which elements you want to be active.

Comment: That `"*"` selector is universal. It's slow and not recommended, but I'm using it to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the `body` element (in place of `this`), then it works:

```
$('body').click(function () {
    var v = $(this).text();
    alert(v); // this prints something, now.
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RKxGA/1/).

You could also, of course, use:

```
$(this.document.body).click(function () {
    var v = $(this).text();
    alert(v); // this prints something, now.
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RKxGA/2/).

If you want only the clicked-element to have its text turn red:

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).css("color", "red");
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RKxGA/3/).

Comment: Thanks David, but in your JS Fiddle example - everything changes to red on 1 click.

Comment: See the updated answer (currently the last code-block and demo).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).click(function () {
```

This is your problem.

Instead of saying `this`, you need to use CSS selectors to specify which elements will change color.

For example, you could try

```
$('div').click(function() { // Will change the color of the divs
     var v = $(this).text();
     alert(v); // this prints nothing !!!!
     $(this).css("color", "red");
}); 
$('p').click(function() {  // Will change the paragraphs
    ...
}); 
$('p, div').click(function() {  // Will work for either one!
    ...
}); 
$('*').click(function() {  // Will work for any element on the page
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your

```
$(this).click(function () {
```

"this" doesn't refer to where the <script> tag is located, but rather it refers to window object. So in essence your code does this:

```
$(window).click(function (){
```

If you want the cow to turn red, when clicking it, change HTML to:

```
<div id="cow">Cow</div>
```

And your script:

```
// callback needs to be inside $(document).ready(fn) to make sure the DOM is ready when trying to use it
$(document).ready(function () {
    // and we need to refer to an explicit element
    $('#cow').click(function (){
        // now we can refer to "this", since inside the click handler's context is the clicked element
        $(this).css({color: 'red'});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify to which element you wanna add a click event. E.g. this will work for all the div-elements:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```